# The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I am a newbie in Hadoop trying to install Hbase in pseudo distributed mode, version hbase-0.98.10.1-hadoop1-bin, with Hadoop 2.5.2 . I am not able to add a table.

**Following error continues when I try to create a table :**

```
client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
```

It finally after displaying the error many times (about 50 times) gives the final error as:

```
ERROR: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
```

Latest entry of log file is:

```
2015-02-23 16:38:39,456 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3017)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:135)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:3031)

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createNamenode(DFSClient.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:281)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1446)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1464)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.getRootDir(FSUtils.java:942)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:533)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3012)
... 5 more
```

Hdbase-site Configuration file:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://master:54310/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/usr/local/Hbase/zookeeper</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>  
<value>true</value>
</property> 
</configuration>
```

**Output of jps is:**

```
7584 Main
8532 HQuorumPeer
4435 SecondaryNameNode
4880 NodeManager
4269 DataNode
7735 FsShell
4592 ResourceManager
4141 NameNode
9128 Jps
3147 ZKServerTool
3651 HRegionServer
2992 HMaster
```

What could be the possible error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: More people will look at your question if you make the title better... (and improve the formatting too!)

Comment: I am not able to use the formatting tool because of ow reputation.

Comment: What ? You can properly format your posts even with low reputation. Just click `edit` below your question, and read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It Just Worked after using a different hbase version. I was using hbase-0.98.10.1-hadoop1-bin, which was not compatible with my hadoop 2.5.2, so I changed hbase version to hbase-X.XX.XX.X-hadoop2-bin (which was compatible for hadoop 2.X ) and followed Apache's installation steps. 
Thank you all..

Comment: Facing the same issue, when trying to Run Hbase 1.0.3 in standalone mode. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Remove the previous version directory and set the path to new file

Answer (score 2):

It means the zookeeper has not the node '/hbase',so create a node  name '/hbase' in zookeeper.go to the zkCli and run the 'create /hbase "" ' command.

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://master:54310/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/Hbase/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
     <property>
        <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
        <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
    </property>
    <property>
         <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
         <value>localhost</value>
    </property>
    <property>
         <name>dfs.replication</name>
         <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
         <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
         <value>localhost</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.master</name> 
        <value>hadoop-master:60000</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

make sure zookeeper should be start and dataDir should be exist.

Comment: Zookeeper starts as HQuorumPeer starts and dataDir exists. I tried your configuration file but it gives the same error. I have updated log file. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

i use it in Talend，when i add hbase connnection in the hadoop cluster, 
the step 2/2, i choose repository in hadoop cluster,when i write server and port(default 2181),point the button 'Check',
the system  prompt：

Connection failure. You must change the Database Settings.
  Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master

then,you need add hadoop properties,click the button and add to the property

zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-unsecure
click ok,then you click 'Check',the system prompt successfull.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct but a bit more lengthy. I was able to solve this problem by just adding following property in hbase-site.xml ( used hbase-1.2.1 )

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/mnt/data/zookeeper</value>
</property>
```

I didnt had to create /mnt/data/zookeeper either. Since I was using HBASE as a standalone I didnt had to run Zookeeper infact it gave an error when I did so

the complete hbase-site.xml configuration file looks like

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>file:///mnt/data/hbase</value>
    </property>
   <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/mnt/data/zookeeper</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```