# ZooKeeper related error on hbase shell start up

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

After logging into hbase shell , got the following error:

> ERROR: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been
>   written by the master. Check the value configured in
>   'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one
>   configured in the master.

Default commands such as list don't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605301/the-node-hbase-is-not-in-zookeeper)

Comment: can you elaborate ? thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).